# MySQL: Why are not all keys of the index used?

Tags: mysql

I've a table with 50 columns. I defined one index (not unique) with the following 6 columns:

```
rdsr_id (int), 
StartOfXrayIrradiation (datetime), 
PatientsBirthDate (date), 
DeviceObserverUID (varchar(100)), 
IdentifiedProtocolShort (varchar(50)), 
RedundantEntryFromDoseSummary (tinyint(1))
```

The table is called report and has around 20'000 rows and is growing. When running the following query, the result shows that only 4 keys of the index are used.

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT r.PatientID, r.StartOfXrayIrradiation, MeanCTDIvol_in_mGy 
FROM report r 
INNER JOIN ct_irradiation_events e ON r.rdsr_id = e.rdsr_id 
INNER JOIN patient_age_categories a ON ( DATEDIFF( r.StartOfXrayIrradiation, r.PatientsBirthDate ) <= a.max_age_days 
  AND DATEDIFF( r.StartOfXrayIrradiation, r.PatientsBirthDate ) >= a.min_age_days 
  AND a.description = 'Erwachsene' ) 
WHERE MeanCTDIvol_in_mGy IS NOT NULL 
AND r.DeviceObserverUID = '2.25' 
AND r.IdentifiedProtocolShort = 'XXXXX' 
AND r.RedundantEntryFromDoseSummary =0 
AND e.CTAcquisitionType != 'Constant Angle Acquisition' 
AND DATEDIFF( r.StartOfXrayIrradiation, '2013-01-06' ) >=0 
AND DATEDIFF( r.StartOfXrayIrradiation, '2014-03-06' ) <=0;
```

result for table report:

```
> id: 1  
> select_type: SIMPLE
> table: r
> type: ref
> possible_keys: TimelineHistogramQueries
> key: TimelineHistogramQueries
> key_len: 4
> ref: rdsr.e.rdsr_id
> rows: 1
> filtered: 100.00
> Extra: Using where
```

So I guess the columns IdentifiedProtocolShort and RedundantEntryFromDoseSummary are not used? The result of the query are 1400 rows. When removing the two columns from the WHERE clause, 9500 rows are found. BTW: I did run "ANALYZE TABLE report" after creating the index, if that matters...

Why are not all keys of the index used? Should I change my index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your `TimelineHistogramQueries` key is a compound key over the six columns that you list *in that order*, then the `key_len` value of 4 (bytes) does indeed indicate that only the `rdsr_id` column is being used from the index: this is supported by the `ref` value of `rdsr.e.rdsr_id`.

You ask why `IdentifiedProtocolShort` and `RedundantEntryFromDoseSummary` (columns 5 and 6 in the index) are not being used. As documented under [Multiple-Column Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/multiple-column-indexes.html):

> MySQL cannot use the index to perform lookups if the columns do not form a leftmost prefix of the index.

If you do not require the columns of this index to be in their current order for any other query, you could merely reorder the columns; otherwise, you may need to define a second index.

Comment: I didn't understand the output of EXPLAIN ... correctly. So key_len 4 means 4 bytes and not 4 keys. I've read the docs before. The 2nd key of the index is StartOfXrayIrradiation and that's the second column of the table report, which is used in the query. Coming from the left side of the index, after rdsr_id StartOfXrayIrradiation is next. So why isn't it used then? Actually I tried to make an index exactly for this query. As you can see, StartOfXrayIrradiation is used multiple times in the query. Do I have to add it multiple times to the index as well? Thank you!

Comment: @nightlyop: To be clear, do you have one index with six columns or six indexes each with one column?

Comment: One index with 6 columns.

Comment: @nightlyop: You are not filtering directly on `StartOfXrayIrradiation`, but rather on the result of some function applied thereon (which cannot benefit from the index).  You can rewrite as `r.StartOfXrayIrradiation BETWEEN '2013-01-06' AND '2013-03-06'` to use the index.  However, you should leave columns upon which you are selecting over a range to the end.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want out of your query.  Leave out patient ID and DOB from your first query if you are interested to see on which dates e.g. your patients had an x-ray, etc.  Unless you are running your analysis by age.  You are confusing the system by trying to index it all.

Comment: all i get with the select statement i need for further analysis. so why should i split the query when i need everything i get with this query? for example the data of adults is handled differently than the data of children so i need DOB. If I'd leave it out here, i'd have to split the data afterwards in a second query...

Comment: First you get all your variables you need.  Indexing puts your values in order.  If you need to see age group, then your query would involve DOB.  If let's say, your next important variable are the dates of x-ray, then add that to the index. Patient ID, will be in your query, but its importance for indexing is secondary.  That is, not so important.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the rdsr_id does not need to be indexed.  Although you still have rdsr_id in your query, it does not need to be indexed.  What you first want to see is the age grouping.  So you index by dob.  Your query will automatically put ids in order but only after your other indexes.